# Webcam notification in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Currently I'm doing my Final Year Project regarding with webcam. I had faced a problem to detect for the live webcam. Is there any way that will appear notification when someone open the webcam in vb.net.

Thank you

Comment: Add some code you tried/approach. So we can help you.

Comment: Webcam or IP Camera?

Comment: its a webcam......

Comment: @jack Kindly help me because im newbies in this language.